# Add refresh button to a Google Scripts Web App

Tags: google-apps-script, page-refresh

I came across the following script last night and it works really nicely to drop files into a Google Drive folder, however I've noticed that there's no clear way to get back to the front page of the app after uploading a file.

https://script.google.com/macros/d/1URDuve8yT1EpDj_WKLHPAuiVt1LWDdUN2kzH-ERUnuxVQqXbi-9I9EfU/edit?usp=drive_web

I realised that this can be achieved by refreshing the page, but my end users are people who are not very computer savvy, and I would like to add a button that refreshes the form to make it a bit easier on them. Unfortunately, I have no idea how to go about doing this.

Can anybody help me out?

Answer (score 1):

The form is has id="myForm" and the status is shown on a div with id="output".

To show the form set is display style property to `block`. You could do this my using something like

```
document.getElementById('myForm').style.display = 'block';
```

To clear the status just add use something like

```
document.getElementById('output').innerHTML = '';
```

Example:

The following examples use HTML/CSS and pure JavaScript to show how to "reset a page" on Google Apps Script

```js
//Initializes the html elements as they are shown after a file is uploaded
document.getElementById('myForm').style.display = 'none';
document.getElementById('output').innerHTML = "File uploaded successfully.";

function resetPage() {
  document.getElementById('myForm').style.display = 'block';
  document.getElementById('output').innerHTML = '';
}
```

```css
input { 
 display:block; margin: 20px; 
}
```

```html
<form id="myForm">
  <input type="text" placeholder="Input 1">
  <input type="text" placeholder="Input 2">
</form>
<div id="output"></div>
<input type="button" onClick="resetPage();" value="Reset">
```

Comment: This clears the output message, like you said, but what I want to occur is for the output message to be cleared and for the initial Name, Email and File Upload fields to become visible again so that users can upload a second file.

Answer (score 1):

Once your file is uploaded successfully this function is called :

```
function fileUploaded(status) {
    document.getElementById('myForm').style.display = 'none';
    document.getElementById('output').innerHTML = status;
}
```

As we can see, this function is hiding the form and putting status in output div, so if we don't hide the form and only update status in output[or maybe you can so a popup/alert on success ?] I think your purpose will be solved.

Something like this should work [Maybe you'll need to style your html a bit]:

```
function fileUploaded(status) {
    document.getElementById('output').innerHTML = status;
}
```

You can add a button with href to the self page[web app], this is a hacky way to refresh.